# Bytecoin wallet stuck on sync

Tags: synchronization, bytecoin

I've been using the Bytecoin wallet 1.1.7.1 and after a complete sync, every time I launch the wallet, it is just stuck on syncing.

Using the OSX version, and I have rolled back to previous versions with no luck.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Trying to shoot off some trades from this wallet.

Comment: Can you define "stuck"? Is the daemon providing any error messages?

Comment: No error messages. Wallet opens, and waits for sync, but it is not downloading the new blocks. [This](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1664981/27367463-c4007254-5612-11e7-9b96-11e26f6addbb.png) illustrates the issue. Bottom left it thinks all blocks are downloaded, but in the center you can see that it knows more blocks need to be downloaded. Balances etc have the loading spinner going.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a different cryptocurrency than Monero.

Comment: It's [on-topic](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23731/are-questions-about-other-cryptonote-coins-on-topic)

Comment: Same issue affecting me. It has been syncing for several hours but has 'stopped' just before the end (it looks about 99% complete). It has been over four hours without syncing another block (or byte or whatever it is). My network is fine, I have restarted the program and it simply won't finish syncing. My coins are now in limbo.

Comment: I haven't fixed my issue, but it appears to be similar to this: https://bytecointalk.org/showthread.php?tid=698

Comment: I figured I would try the CLI wallet they have, and I'm getting an error/warning that says "Proof of work too weak for block...", does that shed light on anything?

Answer (score 2):

Fixed the issue.

Delete all your .sst files. Launch wallet, yes, erase and re-sync. Took 45 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use your wallet as light wallet and use it without downloading the complete blockchain. Just go to preference --> Remote Daemon and change the value to -

bcnrps.ebrahma.com port 8081

you may check this link for more details - http://knowbytecoin.blogspot.in/2017/08/how-to-get-blazing-fast-blockchain-sync.html